# neo4j: Return all nodes on the longest matching patch

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Using neo4j 1.9.4 and py2neo 1.6, I have a binary tree like structure in my graph, where each node has up to two children. However, the graph is not complete, so it might look like this, where "(x)" represents nodes and "[y]" represents relations.

```
                     (root)
                     /     \
                   [0]     [1]
                   /         \
                 (0)         (1)
                /   \          \
              [0]   [1]        [1]
              /       \          \
            (00)      (01)       (11)
            /
          [0]
          /
       (000)
```

I made up some similar example here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ni6t5b (If it is not working for some reason, you can create the graph using the following command:

```
CREATE (node1 { name: '1' }),(node2 { name: '11' }),(node3 { name: '10' }),(node4 { name: '0' }),(node5 { name: '01' }),(node6 { name: '00' }),(node7 { name: '10' }),(root { name:'root' }), root-[:`1`]->node1, node1-[:`1`]->node2, node1-[:`0`]->node7, node2-[:`0`]->node3, root-[:`0`]->node4, node4-[:`1`]->node5, node4-[:`0`]->node6
```

I would like to return all nodes that exist on a (single) **specific** path.

```
START root=node(1) 
MATCH path = root-[?:`0`]-()-[?:`0`]-()-[?:`0`]-() 
RETURN NODES(path)
```

(Note: let ID(root) = 1) This will return all nodes that are in the path, namely (0), (00) and (000)
However, as I don't know what depth each branch has, I also want to query something like this:

```
START root=node(1) 
MATCH path = root-[?:`1`]-()-[?:`1`]-()-[?:`0`]-()-[?:`0`]-() 
RETURN NODES(path)
```

This **should** return all nodes that are on the longest possible path, i.e. (1) and (11). In fact, this query does not return anything. How can I achieve that? Note: For each path, I don't know beforehand, if this path has an existing end node or not. I only want to return all nodes on that path that exist.

Additionally, whats the best way to automatically construct such a query using py2neo (python). For example, I have a list containing several paths of which I need to query each of them. Each path just existing out of '0's and '1's ?

```
list_of_paths = ["0010", "101", "11", "101110"]
```

Thank you, guys!

**EDIT**: Here (http://wes.skeweredrook.com/cypher-longest-path/)  I could find a similar problem. However, the relation type is always the same, which does not hold for my scenario. So I think I can't adopt this solution from there.

**EDIT2:** The suggestions of Wes does *not* solve my problem:

```
START root=node(1)
MATCH path=root-[:`1`|`0`*]->leaf
RETURN path
```

This query returns all possible paths starting from the root-node. What I want is the nodes of **one specific** path.

**EDIT3:** The updated suggestion of Wes does *not* solve my problem either. It only returns the longest existing Path of the whole graph. But I want to query a **specific** path and return all nodes up to the point where the path does not exist in the graph anymore. So I could want to query a really long path, but in fact the path already stops at the first node, e.g. root-[`1`]->()-[`0`]->()-... This query should only return node (1) as the path stops at that point. (Node (1) has no outgoing relation of type `0`)

**EDIT4:** I tried to figure out a solution which works, but it is quite dirty.

```
tree_root, = graph_db.create({"name": "root"}) # create a root

node_list = []
my_path = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1] # path to query
len_of_path = len(my_path)

# add the corresponding number of nodes to the list and name them n0,..nX
for i in range(0,len_of_path):
    node_list.append("n"+str(i))


# construct the query string
my_query_start = 'START root=node({root_id}) MATCH (root)'
my_query_return = ' RETURN'

for i in range(0, len(node_list)):
    my_query_start += '-[?:`' + str(my_path[i]) + '`]->(' + str(node_list[i]) + ')'
    if i == len(node_list)-1:
        my_query_return += ' ' + str(node_list[i])
    else:
        my_query_return += ' ' + str(node_list[i]) + ','

# concatenate the query
complete_query = my_query_start + my_query_return
#print "complete_query:", complete_query

# execute the query
query_paths = neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db, complete_query)
params = {"root_id" : tree_root._id}
my_list_of_nodes = query_paths.execute(**params)

#output results
print "data of my_list_of_nodes:", my_list_of_nodes.data
print "columns of my_list_of_nodes:", my_list_of_nodes.columns
```

Please guys, don't tell me that this is supposed to be the final solution ;-)

Comment: your console example doesn't seem to work--can you try saving it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you possibly use a variable length path with an OR for the reltype?

```
MATCH path=root-***put your partial pattern here***->[:`1`|`0`*]->leaf
WHERE NOT (leaf)-[:`0`|`1`]->()
RETURN path
ORDER BY length(path) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I think it solves your example... but is it more complicated than that?

Comment: This would return all possible paths from the root right? But that is not what I want. I would like to return all nodes on a **specific** path, albeit I can't tell if the end node of this path exists or not

Comment: I meant just using my query with this as the `match` part.

Comment: So you would use the following:
    
    START root=node(1)
    MATCH path=root-[:`1`|`0`*]->leaf
    RETURN path

But that will definitely return all possible paths starting from the root. I only want to return the nodes of **one specific** path.

Comment: I think i didn't express myself clearly enough yet. What your suggestion provides is the longest existing path of the **complete** graph, right? But I only want the longest possible path of a **specific** path. So a scenario would be: Give me all nodes that exist on the possible path root-[`1`]-()-[`1`]-[`0`]-()-[`1`]-(). This should return the nodes (1) and (11) because the path ends there.

Hope this is clear now

Comment: Then put your pattern after the root, along with `-[:`1`|`0`*]->leaf` after it. If your pattern might be the longest already, and you want to return it, then put `*0..`.

Comment: I don't get your last comment. What is it supposed to be good for?

Comment: Updated the answer to show you where I mean to place your pattern. If you want to return the pattern itself if it is the longest, then instead of just `*` do `*0..`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you!